# Why is a double bond not formed with oxygen when reacting this molecule with PCC?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, notation, structural-formula

In my textbook it says that when reacted with PCC, primary alcohols produce an aldehyde. Why is this example different? I do not see any double bonds.
[image]

Comment: I think you are confused about how the aldehyde is being depicted. See [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=cyclohexane+carbaldehyde&espv=2&biw=1176&bih=801&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjspfzY2sTMAhWCcj4KHRoKCtIQ_AUIBigB), and look at the first and third pictures. They are equivalent.

Comment: While I think it is not exactly the best question we have received, the homework close option shouldn't be indiscriminately used - it just becomes a slippery slope and eventually any question that we don't like can just be closed with HW. This has already been happening to some extent.

Comment: That is known as space-saving notation. Carboxylic acids are like this too (RCO2H)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The product shown is an aldehyde. If you count the number of bonds to the carbon with oxygen attached, you can see one single bond to the carbon on the ring, one bond to the hydrogen and therefore there must be two bonds to oxygen - a double bond.

[image]